# How to Pass id value of actionlink to javascript function in my Asp.net Mvc Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have a table for departments. Right now I created controller for every department and every department have index.cshtml.
But they use the same functions. I hard coded their departmentId in every index page.
for example for department IT with departmentId = 1

```
public class ItController : Controller
    {
        // GET: It
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And in It's index page I have hard coded with decleration var id = 1; Like this

```
<div class="panel panel-body">

<div class="col-md-4 table-responsive" id="productsTable"></div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

var id = 1; // for the department that id is 1 so I have to create index for every department and hard code like this


 function AllProductsByDepartmentId(id) {

            var tbl = $('#productsTable');
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '/Home/GetAllProductsByDepartmentId?id=' + id,
                contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    tbl.empty().append(result);
                },
                error: function () {

                }

            });

        }

</script>
```

But to do like this is not good becouse if by some reasen changes Id of department or when I create a new department next time then
I have to hard coded again ...
What I want is first I want to populate those departments in my _Layout dynamicaly from database.
So I created controller

```
    public class DepartmentsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Departments
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.Departments.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
```

And this is my PartialView of Departments and I want to populate it in _Layout.cshtml, but I don't know how to do and how to link them to a function ...

```
@model IEnumerable<Inventory.Models.Departments>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
     @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.DepartmentName???????, ??????, ?????, new { id = item.DepartmentId })

  }
```

and link them to this java function

```
function AllProductsByDepartmentId(id)
{
   // ......
}
```

I think I have to create another common controller to have an index page to all departments.But How to create actionlinks dynamicaly and link them to javascript function. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do. What does your javaScript code (which contains errors) have to do with your `@Html.ActionLink()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi,  I want my department names populate in my _layout dynamicaly I mean my PartialView of Departments populate in my _layout and linking to my java function .. if you check my PartielView of Departments

Comment: So you want to click on the DepartmentName and then use ajax to pass its `DepartmentId` to a `GetAllProductsByDepartmentId()` method? and update the DOM?

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Yes.. Is that possible? or any better way ...?

Comment: Yes. There are a few issues with the code you have shown, so can you also show your `GetAllProductsByDepartmentId()` method so that can be checked as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is already there, do you mean Action controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159835/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-helen-tekie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate links in this case. You `foreach` loop can be just

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <a href="#" class="details" data-id="@item.DepartmentId">@item.DepartmentName</a>
}
```

Note that the value of `DepartmentId` is added to the link as a `data` attribute.

Then you script would be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllProductsByDepartmentId", "Home")';
var tbl = $('#productsTable');
$('.details').click(function() {
    tbl.load(url, { id: $(this).data('id') });
});
```

Comment: I puted foreach in If(Model =! null) { foreach ...} and in my _Layout I added @Html.Partial("_Departments") but departments are not showing in my _layout

Comment: You cannot use `@Html.Partial()` unless you pass a model to it. Use `@Html.Action()` to call the server method that returns a partial view of your departments

Comment: But I do not know what method your wanting to call (all you have shown is an `Index()` method in `DepartmentsController` which already seems to be returning a list of your departments so its not even clear why you need a `_Departments.cshtml` partial)

Comment: In any case, your cannot put a model in a partial (unless its a base model that is used by all views that use that layout)

Comment: I suggest you put any further comments in the chat I started in the question above